# How do I get the 'application_uris' From a Bluemix Cloudfoundry App in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, ibm-cloud

I have a Dev Ops Services Pipeline that I am using to automatically setup a MeteorJS App (really just a NodeJS app) using CloudFoundry and MongoDB.

I have the following deploy script in Dev Opts services:

````
```
#!/bin/bash
cf create-service compose-for-mongodb Standard mongodbbuzzy01
cf push "${CF_APP}" --no-start
mongourl=$(cf env ${CF_APP} | egrep -o 'mongodb://.*"' | rev | cut -c 2- | rev); cf set-env ${CF_APP} MONGO_URL $mongourl
cf restage "${CF_APP}"
```
````

This allows me to get the the mongourl from the `VCAP_SERVICES` and then set it as the MONGO_URL environment variable (in the DevOps shell commands)

I need to do the same for the `ROOT_URL` which Meteor needs as well. It's been about 20 years since my last sed/awk/grep script and I need to pull out the URI of the Bluemix app from the `cf env` text (it's text that includes some JSON).

The result of `cf env <appname>` is a mix of text and JSON objects (so really just text)

```
Getting env variables for app buzzy7build in org Buzzy / space dev as adam.ginsburg@buzzy.buzz...
OK

System-Provided:
{
 "VCAP_SERVICES": {
  "compose-for-mongodb": [
   {
    "credentials": {
.... just curring out details
   }
  }
}


{
 "VCAP_APPLICATION": {
  "application_id": "<some app id>",
  "application_name": "<app name>",
  "application_uris": [
   "<the uri I am trying to get>"
  ],
...
```

So I need some help to extract the `<the uri I am trying to get>` using Bluemix shellscrip (sure if this was NodeJS, it'd be easy)

In Bluemix shell there is NO `jq` (that i am aware of) so just `sed,awk,grep` etc

Any help appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Can you provide the complete `JSON`, a sample of how your actual output looks like? It is easy then to test the commands.

Comment: @Inianthanks please see here https://gist.github.com/adamgins/6e5a842d21306a53d93ef8b7fa634775

Comment: It is not clear which one you are after `"application_uris"` in line 36 or `"uris": [` in line 48

Comment: I think they are both the same, so either

Comment: @Inian thanks heaps, much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do this only if you can *NOT* use `jq` for parsing `JSON`

```
 awk '$0 ~ /application_uris/{getline n; gsub("\"|^[[:space:]]+","",n); print n}' file
<domain name>
```

The `Awk` above will work *only* if your `JSON` is structured as

```
 "application_uris": [
  "<domain name>"
]
```

The logic used in `awk` is it looks for the line containing `application_uris`, gets the next line from the matched line, the `getline n` gets the next line and is stored in the variable `n`. From the received line, we remove the `"` and the leading whitespace using `gsub()`.